# Rx: How to perform an action on inner observable finish with minimum boilerplate?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

In an effort to lean Rx I'm writing a simple application which imitates reading a file and supports cancellation.

It works like this:

- When the user presses the "Run" button the program

  - shows the busy indicator,
  - reads a file in chunks, which is a long process, reporting the length of each one,
  - hides the busy indicator when the reading process is finished (or canceled, see below).
- If the user presses the "Cancel" button the file reading process gets canceled.
- If the user presses the "Run" button while a previous operation is still in progress, the previous operation gets canceled and a new one starts.

I'm looking for a way to **implement this with minimum glue code** while still maintaining the look of a simple sequence of synchronous operations in which the natural control flow is easily seen.

The main problem seems to be hiding the busy indicator when the inner observable (the reader) finishes, the outer observable being the "Run" click event sequence.

So far I came up with these two versions of the main piece of the program:

subscriber-based:

```
IObservable<byte[]> xs =
   runClick
   .Do((Action<EventPattern<EventArgs>>)(_ => ShowBusy(true)))
   .Do(_ => ShowError(false))
   .Select(_ =>
      reader
      .TakeUntil(cancelClick)
      .Publish(ob =>
      {
         ob.Subscribe(
            b => { },
            ex =>
            {
               Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex);
               ShowBusy(false);
               ShowError(true);
            },
            () => ShowBusy(false));
         return ob;
      }))
   .Switch();
xs = xs.Catch<byte[], Exception>(e => xs);
```

and concat-based:

```
IObservable<byte[]> xs =
   runClick
   .Do((Action<EventPattern<EventArgs>>)(_ => ShowBusy(true)))
   .Do(_ => ShowError(false))
   .Select(_ =>
      reader
      .TakeUntil(cancelClick)
      .DoAfter(() =>
         ShowBusy(false)))
   .Switch();
xs = xs.Catch<byte[], Exception>(e =>
{
   Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e);
   ShowBusy(false);
   ShowError(true);
   return xs;
});
```

with one custom method `DoAfter`

```
public static IObservable<T> DoAfter<T>(this IObservable<T> observable, Action action)
{
   IObservable<T> appended = observable.Concat(
      Observable.Create<T>(o =>
      {
         try
         {
            action();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            o.OnError(ex);
            return Disposable.Empty;
         }

         o.OnCompleted();
         return Disposable.Empty;
      }));
   return appended;
}
```

(see the whole application code [here](http://dumpz.org/216885/)).

Neither implementation satisfies me completely: the first is rather verbose, the second forces me to write my own method for a rather simple task which I would expect to be covered by standard means. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out what I was missing was an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229830%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) of the `Do` method. I can use it instead of my custom `DoAfter` method and then the code looks good.

```
IObservable<byte[]> xs =
   runClick
   .Do((Action<EventPattern<EventArgs>>)(_ => ShowBusy(true)))
   .Do(_ => ShowError(false))
   .Select(_ =>
      reader
      .TakeUntil(cancelClick)
      .Do(
         b => { },
         ex =>
         {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex);
            ShowBusy(false);
            ShowError(true);
         },
         () => ShowBusy(false)
      ))
   .Switch();
xs = xs.Catch<byte[], Exception>(e => xs);
```

Comment: FYI, in my experience, a `Catch` like this one will only handle one error. Subsequent errors are not caught (because the resulting observable from the `Catch` behavior doesn't have a `Catch` behavior itself). You might want to look at `Retry`.

Comment: @AndersonImes: It works well, actually. Handles an infinite amount of errors. Could it be that the authors of Rx changed the behavior in 2.0?

Comment: perhaps! I hadn't tried it with 2.0. I'll give it a shot, thanks!

Comment: I think the "infinite errors" stems from the fact that you are resubscribing to the Catch observable when an error is thrown.  By the time the lambda passed to `Catch` is called, `xs` contains the Catch observable itself, thus causing resubscription on error.